# Highcharts PlotLines using specific value from JS array

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/limits",
    dataType: 'json',
        success: function (limits) {
            console.log(limits);
        }
});
```

Console.log(limits):

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {LCL: "0", MAX_LIMIT: "5", MIN_LIMIT: "0"}
1: {LCL: "33.1", MAX_LIMIT: "50", MIN_LIMIT: "3"}
2: {LCL: "14.3", MAX_LIMIT: "18.1", MIN_LIMIT: "13"}
3: {LCL: "0.081", MAX_LIMIT: "0.2", MIN_LIMIT: "0"}
4: {LCL: "69.3", MAX_LIMIT: "100", MIN_LIMIT: "68"}
5: {LCL: "4906", MAX_LIMIT: "7500", MIN_LIMIT: "4560"}
length: 6
```

I use the PlotLines feature in Highcharts. For example:

```
plotLines: [{
    value: ____________ ,
    color: 'green',
    width: 2,
    label: {
        text: 'LCL'
    }
```

For the value, I would like to use **limits[1].LCL** which would be33.1.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create chart after you get the data:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/12ehve",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(limits) {
    createChart(limits);
  }
})

function createChart(limits) {
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...,
    yAxis: {
      plotLines: [{
        value: limits[1].LCL,
        ...
      }]
    }
  });
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4780/

---

Or update the axis in the `success` function:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/12ehve",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(limits) {
    chart.yAxis[0].update({
      plotLines: [{
        value: limits[1].LCL,
        color: 'green',
        width: 2,
        label: {
          text: 'LCL'
        }
      }]
    });
  }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4781/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update

Comment: Worked great. Thanks!